# How to get the title from Navigation drawer menu item

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, onitemclicklistener

I am trying to create a Navigation drawer by getting records from database and showing them in left drawer.

By doing the following I am able to do it successfully, but the problem is, when a menu item is clicked in Navigation drawer I want to get the title of it. But I am only getting the position of it.

```
DrawerLayout  mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

List<DataItems> myTest = myDbAdapter.getValuesFromDb(); // method in DbAdapter class 
                                                       // to get records from db.

// Pass the data to ListView adapter
MyNavigationDrawerAdapter adapter = new MyNavigationDrawerAdapter(
   this, 
   R.layout.drawer_listview_item, 
   myTest);

// Set the adapter for the list view
mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

// set the item click listener
mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new NavigationDrawerItemClickListener());

// navigation drawer click listener
private class NavigationDrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener 
{
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
   {
      Log.i("Position", "" + position); // prints the position successfully

      Log.i("Value", "" + myTest.get(position).getTitle()); // prints null
   }
}
```

Can you please tell me, why this **myTest.get(position).getTitle()** this is null. What am I missing here?

Comment: why dont you create a string array and fetch values according to the position

Comment: try to debug your code for the values in `myTest`

Comment: @SMR What you mean to say I should try doing this: 
`String[] array = new String[...]` instead of doing List<DataItems> myTest?

Comment: myTest.get(position).getTitle() is null because you did not set any title in your `Model` class. Post your model code.

Comment: @BharathMg if I try this `myTest.get(position)` I still get the null value.

Comment: Then pls check if your myTest is empty. Or if any value exists for the position.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
List<DataItems> myTest = new List<DataItems>(myDbAdapter.getValuesFromDb());
```

instead of using

```
List<DataItems> myTest = myDbAdapter.getValuesFromDb();
```

Comment: This gives an error that: 
**ArrayList<DataItems> cannot be resolved to a type**

Comment: sorry change it to whatever your **myDBAdapter.getValuesFromDB** is returning I guess it is List<DataItems>

Answer (score 0):

In your onClickListener try:

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView <?> parent, View view, int position, long id){

  DataItems dataItem = adapter.getItem(position);
  String mString = dataItem.getTitle();

 }
```